# CLOSE all Divs with slide before a new one OPENS using jquery SLIDETOGGLE // visible / hide?

Tags: jquery, hide, show, slidetoggle, visible

I'm having a problem with opening/closing divs at the same time. I've read a lot about it and tried like everything but nothing seems to work... this is how it is supposed to look like:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nGabd/)

This is the code I got. It works perfectly with one DIV:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
}); });
```

I want this to work with 3 divs or more: That the currently opened div closes up with a slide as soon as a new link is clicked and the div comes up with a slide.

Would be so happy to hear from you :-) Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly I think you're after something like this:

```
$('a.link').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var slideSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('link', 'slide');

  // slide down the div which corresponds to the clicked anchor,
  $(slideSelector).slideDown(500, function() {
    // slide the rest up
    $('div.slide').not($(slideSelector)).slideUp(500);
  });

  // or do it in the reverse order
  $('div.slide').not($(slideSelector)).slideUp(500, function() {
    $(slideSelector).slideDown(500);
  });      

});
```

Here's the markup I used for the above example:-

```
<a id="link1" class="link" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a id="link2" class="link" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a id="link3" class="link" href="#">Link 3</a>

<div class="slide" id="slide1">Slide Example #1</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide2">Slide Example #2</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide3">Slide Example #3</div>
```

Notice that the `<a>`'s and `<div>`'s have all been given `id`'s, these are used to relate the two together (take a look at the `slideSelector`).

[Here's a fiddle which will toggle between each of the above examples each time a link is clicked](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/W6se7/2/)

This is just one way of doing it, another way for example would be to wrap the links and divs in separate containers, and then use the `index()` in order to select the div which corresponds to the clicked link, however the links and divs would have to appear in the same order for this to work.

Comment: Hey deifwud, thank you so much for your answer!! It's almost perfect :P Just one thing: is it possible to open/close the divs in this order? click -> shown div closes completely (slideup) -> new div opens (slidedown). Would love to hear from you!!

Answer (score 0):

`$(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();` try adding this line. hope it may help.

ok i didnt got you at the first time so i just posted that part:
add this
 `$('.menu').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
    });`
this will help. actually what your code is doing at first is only clicking  with class show_hide. if you want your hyperlink to work you have use the class on hyperlinks.

Comment: thanks! [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nGabd/19/) this closes the open div, but how can I do this with seperate links clicked?